# how to generate Function yii2 model in master master model

Tags: inheritance, model-view-controller, yii2, extend

i am working with yii2 advanced application , i have created a master model, my goal is to create the same functions of child model and put them in master model to be generated automatically without go back to gii tool.
i start like this :

```
<?php

namespace common\components;

use Yii;

class BaseModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return  '{{%'.Yii::$app->controller->id.'}}';
    }

    public function rules()
    {       

    }

    public function attributesLabels()
    {       

    }
    ...etc
}
```

Any idea how to generate rules() and attributeLabels() functions ??
I think it's the same way like the generator do it, but i don't know how to start.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a good idea to do this in Yii2. I mean, if you use a `User` model from a controller that isn't `UserController` you will be making reference to a table that has nothing to do with it.

For example, with the same `User` model class when you try to login to your site using the default `site/login` controller/action your `User` model will try to find the user you are trying to login with in the `site` table. It will crash and burn.

The same can be said about the `rules()` method. There are ocassions when you need to add validation rules that can't be infered from the database table and need to be defined by the programmer for the model.

It might seem like a good idea for a few instances when your especific requirements fit with what you are trying to do, however it is a really bad practice.

Comment: For model User i will not extend it , but for the others it's possible ans when i need other validation rules i will have to override the function rules in child model .

Comment: And in case you need to use a model in a controller that doesn't have the exact same name? It might work for simple CRUDS, however it still is a really bad idea with anything more complex than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it manually,

```
<?php

namespace common\models;//Change it, that's correct one

use Yii;

class BaseModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord

{

   public static function tableName()
   {
       return  '{{%'.Yii::$app->controller->id.'}}';
   }

   public function rules()
   {       
      return [
          // some base rules
          [['name', 'email', 'subject', 'body'], 'required'],
      ];
   }

   public function attributeLabels()
   {
       //Some dummy labels
       return [
           'name' => 'Your name',
           'email' => 'Your email address',
           'subject' => 'Subject',
           'body' => 'Content',
       ];
   }
    ...etc
}
```

---

You can actually delete your `rules()` and `attributeLabels()` so it will be passed dynamically (rules will be empty) and for attributes, as it said in docs,
`By default, attribute labels are automatically generated from attribute names. The generation is done by the method yii\base\Model::generateAttributeLabel(). It will turn camel-case variable names into multiple words with the first letter in each word in upper case. For example, username becomes Username, and firstName becomes First Name.` [Link to it.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#attribute-labels)

Or if you want you can add some basic staff in Base model, and then do the rest in you child model
like this:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;
use common\models\BaseModel;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

class BaseModel extends BaseModel

{
   public function rules()
   {
       //Get you base model rules, there will be only those
       //that are acceptable for all of your models
       $rules = parent::rules();
       //merge them with new ones, in this example
       //we have property `group` with `string` validator
       //if you want to override your basic rules pass it as second
       //param
       return ArrayHelper::merge($rules, [[['group'], 'string']]);
   }

   public function attributeLabels()
   {
       //same is here
       $attributeLabels = parent::attributeLabels();
       return ArrayHelper::merge($attributeLabels, ['group' => 'Group name']);

      // OR (use only one) for only new once
      $attributeLabels = parent::attributeLabels();
      $attributeLabels['group'] = 'Some new name';
      return $attributeLabels;
   }
    ...etc
}
```

---

If you have further question or if anything is not understandable, let me know.

Comment: Noo it's not what i search for , my function rules must be dynamic, because i will delete it from all the child models that extend from Basemodel.
Conclusion i have 5 model so i will have 5 rules function , mu purpose is to put 1 function that work for all the model for code code optimisation.
Like i am doing it in  : function tableName() instead of this 

public static function tableName()
{
    return  '{{%personne}}';
}

Do you understand me ??

Comment: the solution you gave me it's for child models, and not master model that extend from yii/db/activrecord